# How to collate the information from three temp tables into one, including a COUNT function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created three temp tables in order to get three different sets of results - temporary workers, perm workers and dates in DATE format for the last 20 years.

```
> -- Temp Table for Contract Entries
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM
(Select U.Id,
        UWH.Role,
        USI.Title,
        Cast(USI.StartDate As Date) AS StartDate,
        Cast(USI.EndDate As Date) AS EndDate
From    UserWorkHistory      UWH
Join    Users                U    On UWH.UserId = U.Id
Join    UserStoryItems       USI  On U.Id = USI.UserId
Join    UserWorkHistoryTypes UWHT On UWH.UserWorkHistoryTypeId = UWHT.Id
Where   
(
    U.Location Like '%Great Britain%'
 Or U.Location Like '%United Kingdom%'
 Or U.Location Like '%England%'
 Or U.Location Like '%UK'
 Or U.Location Like '%U.K.%'
)
and    UWHT.Id = 1
And    USI.UserStoryItemTypeId = 1
And    Cast(USI.StartDate As Date) > DateAdd(Year, -20, GetDate())
And 
(
     (
        UWH.Role LIKE '%Contract%'
     Or UWH.Role LIKE '%Contractor%'
     Or UWH.Role LIKE '%Freelance%'
     Or UWH.Role LIKE '%Non-perm%'
     Or UWH.Role LIKE '%non-permanent%'
    )
    Or 
    (
        USI.Title LIKE '%Contract%'
     Or USI.Title LIKE '%Contractor%'
     Or USI.Title LIKE '%Freelance%'
     Or USI.Title LIKE '%Non-perm%'
     Or USI.Title LIKE '%non-permanent%'
     Or USI.Title LIKE '%self-made%'
    )
  )
  ) AS EntriesContract

>-- Temp Table for Perm Entries
 SELECT *
INTO #temp2
FROM
(Select  U.Id,
        UWH.Role,
        USI.Title,
        Cast(USI.StartDate As Date) AS Startdate,
        Cast(USI.EndDate As Date) AS EndDate
From    UserWorkHistory      UWH
Join    Users                U    On UWH.UserId = U.Id
Join    UserStoryItems       USI  On U.Id = USI.UserId
Join    UserWorkHistoryTypes UWHT On UWH.UserWorkHistoryTypeId = UWHT.Id
Where   
(
    U.Location Like '%Great Britain%'
 Or U.Location Like '%United Kingdom%'
 Or U.Location Like '%England%'
 Or U.Location Like '%UK%'
 Or U.Location Like '%U.K.%'
)
and    UWHT.Id = 1
And    USI.UserStoryItemTypeId = 1
And    Cast(USI.StartDate As Date) > DateAdd(Year, -20, GetDate())
And 
(
     (
        UWH.Role NOT LIKE '%Contract%'
     Or UWH.Role NOT LIKE '%Contractor%'
     Or UWH.Role NOT LIKE '%Freelance%'
     Or UWH.Role NOT LIKE '%Non-perm%'
     Or UWH.Role NOT LIKE '%non-permanent%'
    )
    Or 
    (
        USI.Title NOT LIKE '%Contract%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%Contractor%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%Freelance%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%Non-perm%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%non-permanent%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%self-made%'
    )
) 
)AS EntriesPerm

>-- Create Temp Table of Dates
SELECT *
INTO #temp3
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(USI.StartDate AS Date) AS Dates
FROM UserStoryItems USI 
WHERE CAST(USI.StartDate AS Date) BETWEEN '1997-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
)
AS Dates
<
```

I would like to create a fourth table of results (either as a temp table or using a SELECT query) to give me three columns:
1) The dates that are returned in the third temp table (#temp3)

2) The COUNT(U.Id) from the Temporary Workers table (#temp1) as long as the date returned in the first column is between the StartDate and EndDate

3) 2) The COUNT(U.Id) from the Permanent Workers table (#temp2) as long as the date returned in the first column is between the StartDate and EndDate

The aim is to get a table that can tell me, for example, how many temp workers there were vs how many perm on 2009-09-01 00:00:00. Eventually I would like to put the results into a graph.

I am having trouble with the next step. My first attempt was:

```
INSERT INTO #temp4 (Dates, CountTemp, CountPerm)
SELECT #temp3.Dates, COUNT(#temp.Id), COUNT(#temp2.Id)
FROM #temp
JOIN #temp2 ON #temp.StartDate=#temp2.StartDate
JOIN #temp3 ON #temp.StartDate=#temp3.StartDate
WHERE #temp3.Dates BETWEEN #temp2.StartDate AND #temp3.StartDate
GROUP BY #temp3.Dates
ORDER BY #temp3.Dates DESC
```

However the error "Invalid column name 'StartDate'. Invalid column name 'StartDate'. Invalid object name '#temp4'." was returned.

Any suggestions? Forgive my ignorance, I am new to posting questions on Stack and to SQL.

Comment: well yes in temp3 there is no field named `StartDate` . how are you jioning? is it the same as Dates?

Comment: To the downvoter - thank you for your feedback. To help make future contributions better, could you elaborate on why this is a bad question? I want to be a strong part of the community. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Zeina - yes you're right, maybe this is the problem. Instead of StartDates (which is the name of the column) I should put #temp.Cast(USI.StartDate As Date)?

Comment: In order to insert into #temp4 you ahve to create it first, `CREATE TABLE #Temp4 (Dates DATETIME, CountTemp INT, CountPerm INT)`

Comment: no this won't work either, however I ddnt understand yout attempt to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this as your final INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO #temp4 (Dates, CountTemp, CountPerm)
SELECT 
#temp3.Dates
, (SELECT COUNT(#temp.Id) FROM #temp WHERE #temp3.Dates BETWEEN #temp.StartDate AND #temp.EndDate) AS CountTemp
, (SELECT COUNT(#temp2.Id) FROM #temp2 WHERE #temp3.Dates BETWEEN #temp2.StartDate AND #temp2.EndDate) AS CountPerm
FROM #temp3
ORDER BY #temp3.Dates DESC
```

However unless you have a specific need for all those temp tables the problem would likely be better solved other ways such as creating a view to return the employee start and end dates and a column to specify permanant or temporary then write a query to get the count for each type. Another way is to use a common table expression, something like this:

```
WITH All_Employees AS
(Select  U.Id,
        UWH.Role,
        USI.Title,
        Cast(USI.StartDate As Date) AS Startdate,
        Cast(USI.EndDate As Date) AS EndDate,
        Case WHEN UWH.Role Like '%Contract%' 
            Or UWH.Role Like '%Freelance%' 
            Or UWH.Role Like '%Non-perm%' 
            Or USI.Title Like '%Contract%'
            Or USI.Title Like '%Freelance%'
            Or USI.Title Like '%Non-perm%'
            Or USI.Title Like '%self-made%'
        Then 'Temporary' Else 'Permanant' End AS Employee_Type
From    UserWorkHistory      UWH
Join    Users                U    On UWH.UserId = U.Id
Join    UserStoryItems       USI  On U.Id = USI.UserId
Join    UserWorkHistoryTypes UWHT On UWH.UserWorkHistoryTypeId = UWHT.Id
Where   
U.Location Like '%Great Britain%'
 Or U.Location Like '%United Kingdom%'
 Or U.Location Like '%England%'
 Or U.Location Like '%UK%'
 Or U.Location Like '%U.K.%'
 )

SELECT 
CAST(USI.StartDate AS Date) AS Dates
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM All_Employees E WHERE CAST(USI.StartDate AS Date) BETWEEN E.StartDate AND E.EndDate AND E.Employee_Type = 'Temporary') AS Temporary_Employees
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM All_Employees E WHERE CAST(USI.StartDate AS Date) BETWEEN E.StartDate AND E.EndDate AND E.Employee_Type = 'Permanant') AS Permanant_Employees
FROM UserStoryItems USI 
WHERE CAST(USI.StartDate AS Date) BETWEEN '1997-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Just to note you do not need '%Contract%' and '%Contractor%' in you criteria as '%Contract%' will return both results anyway, likewise with '%non-perm%' and '%non-permanant%'.

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you so much! It makes much more sense to do it the second way. And of course you're right about '%contract%, I didn't think of that. This has worked well for me and I really appreciate your help!